# MVC route with id and sub-action

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api

I can't figure out what I need to do with MVC routing to make this work

Here's my one route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

The request **/Shipments/** works great.

The request **/Shipments/3/Packages** works great.

The request **/Shipments/3** however fails with the error:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request:
>   System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Api.Controllers.RequisitionsController+PackageRequisitionWithTracking]
>   GetPackageRequisitions(Int32) on type
>   Api.Controllers.RequisitionsController Api.Models.ShipmentRequisition
>   GetShipmentRequisitions(Int32) on type
>   Api.Controllers.RequisitionsController

It can't seem to differentiate between:

```
// No ActionName    
public ShipmentRequisition GetShipmentRequisitions(int id)
```

and

```
[ActionName("Packages")]
public IQueryable<PackageRequisitionWithTracking> GetPackageRequisitions(int id)
```

I would have thought the lack of action name on the get shipment by id would allow that route to work.

Comment: Could you post your action in here?

Comment: I included the signatures of the two actions that are clashing. It's the routing getting confused which to pick that's the problem, not the contents of the methods.

Comment: you could set the GetShipmentRequisitions action as the default action for your route.

Answer (score 0):

It's been answered here a couple of times already - you can't mix REST style routing (where you ask for the controller with a GET, and it returns the default Get action) and RPC routing (where you provide explicit action name in the route) in a *single controller*.

Web API will not know which action to use as the default "GET" action.

There is an issue open on that with the Web API team on ASP.NET Web Stack's Codeplex - http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/184.

Your best bet for now is to separate your controllers into ones that use REST routing (routing based on HTTP verbs) and RPC routing (routing based on action names in the URL).